# SQL sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get (count of completed modules) along with (count of course modules) in a (course) for an (user)

Tables:

```
course_modules - will have all the course modules
course_modules_completion - will have all the users with completed modules.
```

I want to show all the three in one query like example:

```
(course)  (count of course modules) (count of completed modules) (userid)
   3               20                        5                      12
   5               20                        8                      7
```

Here is the query I tried :

```
 SELECT
    c.fullname, count(cm.id) AS "coursemodules", cmc.userid,
    (SELECT count(cmc.coursemoduleid) 
     FROM mdl_course c 
         JOIN mdl_course_modules cm 
         JOIN mdl_modules m 
         JOIN mdl_course_modules_completion cmc ON c.id = cm.course 
           AND cm.module = m.id 
           AND cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id 
           AND cmc.userid = 12 
           AND cm.course = 7 
           AND cmc.completionstate BETWEEN 1 AND 10) AS "completedmodules"
    FROM
    mdl_course c 
       JOIN mdl_course_modules cm 
       JOIN mdl_modules m 
          ON c.id = cm.course AND cm.module = m.id AND cm.course = 7
```

It shows an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(cmc.coursemoduleid) FROM mdl_course c JOIN mdl_course_modules cm JO' at line 3
```

Could anyone suggest me?

```
Data for course_modules
id course moduletypeid
1    3     9 
2    3     9
3    3     17
4    5     20
5    5     18

Data for course_modules_completion
id  coursemoduleid userid
1      153           12
2      154           12
3      155           11
4      120           12
5      167            11
```

Comment: show some data for `course_modules` and `course_modules_completion` and if possible provide a sqlfiddel

Comment: I have given the data of both the tables

Comment: You are joining tables in wrong way and fetching sub-query data in main query with wrong aliases..we can help you if you provide some table wise sample data.

Comment: relation bet `course_modules` and `course_modules_completion`??/

Comment: as per my understanding your 2nd table should contain courseid while it is missing there..is table data correct. Also your query is showing more tables and fields but you have updated less..

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
FROM mdl_course c 
         JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON c.id = cm.course
         JOIN mdl_modules m ON cm.module = m.id
         JOIN mdl_course_modules_completion cmc ON 
           cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id 
WHERE
           AND cmc.userid = 12 
           AND cm.course = 7 
           AND cmc.completionstate BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

UPDATE

You can try to get rid of the subquery in SELECT and replace it with

```
SUM(if (cmc.completionstate BETWEEN 1 AND 10,1,0) AS "completedmodules"
```

Comment: Thank You Vignesh and StanislavL for your support, but I couldn't get like the output I stated along with userid

Comment: I have userid in the 2nd subquery, it is difficult to take the userid